# Flutter FCM consume initial message

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

To get initial message when app has been launched from notification:

```
final remoteMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
final data = remoteMessage?.data;
// Do something with data
```

It works. But, docs also says:

> Once the [RemoteMessage] has been consumed, it will be removed and
> further calls to [getInitialMessage] will be `null`.

However, if I call again:
`remoteMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();`

It still contains remote message. How do I actually set it's consumed and should be null? My app flow: remote message is retrieved after login. After logout/login again, second call still returns the same remote message, which should not happen, because app is going to perform some actions if remote message is not null.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into this issue. I also want to "consume" the remote message but don't know how to. We might be using it wrong or something is wrong with it, or we are misunderstanding something :)

Anyways just want to share the temporary work-around I did while there is no legitimate fix/answer for it:
Basically just kept track of the remote messages (by messageId) that were already handled so that remote messages will only be handled once.

Comment: `Basically just kept track of the remote messages (by messageId) that were already handled so that remote messages will only be handled once.` - that's exactly what I did too. But still, it's not clear what does `consume` mean here. Apparanetly, it means nothing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35736381)